# Page refreshes and content is not created

Tags: 7, nodes, users

I have a website in `Drupal` and I restored site using `drush` from the backup files of the site.

After restoring the site, I can't create **content** and even I can't do a **cache clear** through the admin interface.

I am getting **403 error** when creating content and clearing cache.

Comment: can you login into admin?

Comment: Yes I can go all the way through the admin pages, but it won't save the content etc.

Comment: Are you able to clear cache through DRUSH

Comment: check error_log in the root directory of Drupal

Comment: @nitvirus, yes, works as far as i know with that

Comment: @AgA, no such file exists in the directory

Comment: check logs in admin/reports/dblog 
and try seeing your mysql logs for errors.

Comment: /var/log/mysql* (mysql/ mysql.err and mysql.log) are all empty :(

Comment: dblog has nothing applicable

Comment: hmmm...have you enabled logging and error at admin/config/development/logging

also try restarting your mysql server , clear the cache and then creating content

Comment: @nitvirus, I never touched that, but I did look, and its enabled, I get everything else, I'll try restarting mysql, and clearing my cache

Comment: Also, I just cleared my browser cache and now I get access denied on it, and I don't believe its letting me login

Comment: My site isn't that big yet, I believe I'll just mark down the modules I have in sites/all/modules/ and reinstall drupal, it would probably easier for me.